Can we say "to be done with something" to generally mean we finish something completely or just some parts of it?
I want my daughter to be well-organized.
She got a test sheet with several questions. I often say "it's better to study in several short sessions than fewer long ones" (I did a research and it seems this is a correct expression but I am not sure of there is a shorter / better way to say it).
But this question is not about that expression.
Because I encourage her to study in several short sessions, so she might finish some questions (not all) on her test sheet and then goes to play. But before she goes to play she must put away the sheet or she might lose it.
Normally, "to be done with it" means "to finish it completely"
Does "to be done with your sheet" mean "to finish using your sheet and not worry how many questions are finished on it"?
Is it correct to say "Put your sheet back where it was when you're done with it" to generally mean she must put the sheet away whenever she finishes using the sheet and it doesn't matter how many questions she has finished?

That's why we invented the phrase "for now".  Are you done with that for now? for now is assuming you might need or want to come back to it later. Put it away if you're done with it for now. put it away means "put it where it belongs". If your daughter has completed it, she can say I'm done with it for good.  That means I don't need or want it any longer. If she becomes rebellious, she cay say "I'm done with you for good."

To be done with something does not mean that it is finished
Idiomatically, to be done with something means you’re not going to engage with it again.
It can mean that you won’t engage with it because it’s complete, but it also be incomplete and you’re just not going to complete it. So, your daughter could be “done with studying” because she has finished all the study she needs to do or because she’s just not going to study and is content that that might mean she fails the test.

Yes, that is correct:

Put your sheet back where it was when you're done with it.

when you're done with it means the same as when you're done using it or when you're done working on it.
It doesn't imply you've completed it; it simply means that you're finished with it for the time being.
I think it's slightly different if you eliminate with it, for example:

Put it back when you're done.

To me, there is a stronger implication that you've completed it, but it's not a foregone conclusion.
